# Java program simulating finally not called

Tags: java

I was trying to write a sample program to identify on what cases JVM doesn't call finally() as mentioned in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html.

---

Note: If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the **thread** executing the try or catch code is **interrupted** or **killed**, the finally block **may not** execute even though the application as a whole continues.

---

But, in all the cases I wrote, finally is being called (Except `thread.suspend()` without `thread.resume()` and `System.exit()` cases). Even finally is called in `thread.stop()` as opposed to mentioned in various other forum (code snippet below).

Can anybody help? Thanks.

```
try {
    final Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings(value = "deprecation")
        public void run() {
            thread.stop();
            // thread.suspend();
        }
    }).start();
    while (true)
        Thread.sleep(1000);
} finally {
    System.out.print("finally called after stop");
}
```

Comment: It does say "may not execute", not "is guaranteed not to execute"...

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc for [`Thread.stop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29):

> The thread represented by this thread is forced to stop whatever it is
>   doing abnormally and to throw a newly created ThreadDeath object as an
>   exception.

So this method actually throws an `Exception`, therefore `finally` is still called.

Comment: Note that The `Exception` is thrown in the executing `Thread` and therefore caught somewhere in the scheduler.

Comment: I agree. But can we write a program where finally() is not at all called?

Comment: @Chandru the only way to _guarantee_ that `finally` is not called is to call `System.exit(0)` or to `kill -9` (unix) the program.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, Thanks. I tried every possible way I know of and I seem to end up the way you mentioned. May be, Oracle folks can edit java doc and remove "may not" :)

Answer (score 0):

To complement @Boris

From javadoc:

> An application should not normally try to catch ThreadDeath unless it must do some extraordinary cleanup operation **(note that the throwing of ThreadDeath causes finally clauses of try statements to be executed before the thread officially dies)**. If a catch clause catches a ThreadDeath object, it is important to rethrow the object so that the thread actually dies.